# Terminal prompt 'saving' certain commands on up-arrow

Tags: terminal, bash

I added a little bit of shell scripting to my prompt for fun. It alternates the colors of prompt items randomly. I did it purely because a gray screen gets boring after awhile. The following is my prompt in .bash-profile:

```
function next_hue
{
    color1=$((31 + (++color % 7)))   # set 31 to 30 for dark on light
    color1=$((31 + (++color % 7)))
    PS1="\n\e[0:${color}m[\W]\n\e[0:${color}m[\u]-> $reset" # set 1 to 0 for     dark on light
}
```

This alternates the color of my prompt. Yay!

The problem is that sometimes the shell will get "stuck." For instance, the shell is usually like this:

```
directory
[username]->
```

If I have recently run the `docker run` command, and I up-arrow into the history, `docker run gets stuck and I end up with this:

```
directory
[username]->docker run
```

If I add a new command it stacks on `docker run`:

```
directory
[username]->docker runcd /some/path
```

I have to use `ctrl-c` or some other such option, and I can't use the `docker-run` command again unless I type it all out. WHat could be causing this error? I have looked over my prompt quite a bit and I think it is okay, but it was confusing to figure out in the first place.

Comment: Where do you call `next_hue` from?

Comment: I don't think it is related to your prompt.  More likely there is something weird in your ~/.inputrc messing with the command history.

Answer (score 2):

You're not escaping the non-printing characters in your prompt. [See this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053), and use "`\[`" and "`\]`" around the colors, something like this (untested) for example...

```
PS1="\n\e[0:\[${color}\]m[\W]\n\e[0:\[${color}\]m[\u]-> $reset"
```

You may need to tweek that. Like I said, this is untested so I may have inserted a "`\]`" in the middle of a colour code. For my prompt I do the escaping when I initialise the colour variables:

```
PS1_FG="\[$(tput setaf 223)\]"  # Prompt foreground colour (223 = pale orange/brown)
```

For what it's worth, I can highly recommend using `tput` when you're dealing with control codes. It makes your scripts more portable, and (IMHO) is easier to read.